# Tensorflowjs yields shape error when training

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am trying to train a simple network model with tensorflow  version `tfjs@0.12.0` and I am using the layers API. It is just a network that takes two numbers as an input and returns the same two numbers - so the network should try to learn the identity matrix.

I am training with 6 examples, therefore the shape of my inputs and outputs are both [6,2] however I get a shape error.

My javascript file is below:

```
function setup() {
    const model = tf.sequential();

    const hidden = tf.layers.dense({
        units: 4,
        useBias: true,
        activation:'sigmoid',
        inputDim: [2],
    });

    model.add(hidden);

    const output = tf.layers.dense({
        units: 2,
        activation:'sigmoid',
    });

    model.add(output);

    model.compile({
        optimizer: 'sgd',
        loss: 'meanSquaredError',
    });

    const xs = tf.tensor2d([
        [0.25, 0.92],
        [0.12,0.3],
        [0.4,0.74],
        [0.3,0.82],
        [0.09,0.95],
        [0.53,0.2],
    ]);

    const ys = tf.tensor2d([
        [0.25, 0.92],
        [0.12,0.3],
        [0.4,0.74],
        [0.3,0.82],
        [0.09,0.95],
        [0.53,0.2],
    ]);


    console.log(model.fit(xs,ys));
}
```

However when I run the script I get a shape error:

```
Promise { <state>: "rejected" }
sketch.js:46:5
Error: Error when checking input: expected dense_Dense1_input to have shape [,2], but got array with shape [6,2].
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `inputDim: 2` or `inputShape: [2]` within your `hidden` layer declaration.